# Accept inform response coming from a different port than the request destination port

Tags: pysnmp

The following code works when the response source port is 162 but seems to raise an "Unknown SNMP community name encountered" exception when the response source port is dynamic.

Is it related to CommunityData / UdpTransportTarget mapping ? Any ways to accept responses with source port different from the request destination port ?

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

def send_notification(host, community):
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
        sendNotification(
            SnmpEngine(),
            CommunityData(community),
            UdpTransportTarget((host, 162)),
            ContextData(),
            'inform',
            NotificationType(
                ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.90000.1')
            ).addVarBinds(
            ('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.90000.1', Integer32(1)),
            ('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.90000.2', Integer32(2))
            )
        )
    )

    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication)
    elif errorStatus:
        print('%s: at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(), 
            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))        

send_notification('127.0.0.1', 'mycomm')
```

Comment: I think if your peer is sending ACK from a random port i.e. not from the very port where your notification originator has sent its message, the sender won't take the response as authentic... What's your use-case? Why do you need this asymmetrical interaction?

Comment: I need to bulk send inform requests to Cisco routers to trigger events.

Comment: Linux snmptrap -Ci command and Perl Net-SNMP module seem to accept the responses. But no luck with pysnmp HLAPI.